# Using angular widgets in a non-angular website

Tags: javascript, angular, widget

I want to use the following widget in a non-angular website, by just calling the tag `<app-root>` anywhere I want in a page, multiple times. That means each tag should be a different instance.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div class="widget-container">
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .widget-container {
      width: 40%;
      border: 1px solid grey;
    }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'This is an angular widget';
}
```

I tried to do this by, taking an AOT build of the angular project which I used to develop this simple widget and import the script files and css file in to this other non-angular site (using WAMP) . But, it doesn't work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SimpleWidget</title>
    <base href="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
<app-root></app-root>
<app-root></app-root>
<app-root></app-root>
<app-root></app-root>
<app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.12e8db88bf510206182f.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.35726d60cdf25fecc5f1.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.4ec6f75eb1fd6ed6bd56.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.db9607812bd105b9d1c8.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually, this `index.html` file is the html file generated from the AOT build of angular 4. Anyway, this html file can be on drupal or wordpress. Can anyone describe how to achieve this requirement?

#### If I have made a mistake, please enlighten me.

#### Thanks in advance!

Comment: hello, did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: I'm afraid I still couldn't find a proper answer for this.